# Showing that $\mathbb{P}(V = 1 - |2U -1|) = 1$ for $U,V \sim Unif[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Assume $U$ and $V$ are uniform$(0,1)$ random variables with the following joint distribution:
>   $$F(u,v)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} u, &0\leq u \leq v/2 \leq 1/2\\
> v/2, & 0 \leq v/2 \leq u < 1 - v/2 \\
> u + v - 1, & 1/2 \leq 1 - v/2 \leq u \leq 1 \end{array} \right.$$
>   The exercise is to show that $\mathbb{P}(V = 1 - |2U -1|) = 1$ and $\text{Cov}(U,V) = 0$.

It seems a simple exercise, but my probability skills got a bit rusty and the book I'm following does not delve deep into the technicalities. How would we proceed from here?

It seems we are interested in finding $P(Z = 0) = 1 - P(Z > 0)$, where $Z := V - 1 + |2U-1|$, but it's not clear how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: For the first question, consider the locus $$L=\{(u,v)\in[0,1]^2\mid v=1-|2u-1|\}$$ and a square $$K=(u_1,u_2]\times(v_1,v_2]$$ such that $$K\cap L=\varnothing$$ Show that $$P((U,V)\in K)=0$$ using only the CDF $F$, and conclude.